# how to NAT site to site VPN web traffic?

Tags: vpn, cisco, nat, site-to-site-vpn

I have 2 Cisco routers and they are connected via GRE over IPsec.
All of the traffic from the first router is being routed to the 2nd router with a default route.
I need to access internet from the 2nd router.

How should I config the NAT on the 2nd router so that the clients behind the 1st router can access the internet from the 2nd router?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it in dynamips and it seems to work fine.

```
interface Tunnel0
 ip address 192.168.100.1 255.255.255.252
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 tunnel source Serial0/0
 tunnel destination 192.168.1.2
 crypto map vpn
!
interface Serial0/1
 ip address 201.5.12.1 255.255.255.252
 ip nat outside
 serial restart-delay 0
!
ip route 172.16.1.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.100.2
ip nat inside source list 10 interface Serial0/1 overload
access-list 10 permit 172.16.1.0 0.0.0.255
```

[source](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk648/tk361/technologies_tech_note09186a0080094e77.shtml#topic5)